# Can someone explain why we need to write ...state(previous state) when we are updating the state with the new values

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Here is the code for my authReducer that I am implementing where I have different cases for actions :

```
const authReducer = (state = { authData: null, loading: false, error: false }, action) =\> {
  switch (action.type) {
     case "AUTH_START":
         return { ...state, loading: true, error: false };
     case "AUTH_SUCCESS":
         localStorage.setItem("Profile", JSON.stringify({ ...action?.data }));
         return { ...state, authData: action.data, loading: false, error: false };
     case "AUTH_FAIL":
         return { ...state, loading: true, error: true };
     default:
         return state;
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

Comment: Stop using Redux, The redux team recommend now using [redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) it's much better and it was actually made at first just to solve this problem, they created a package called [immerjs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) which solves exactly your problem. When your code starts to grow, it will become a nightmare to read all these reducers, and it will cause you nights and nights to debug,

Answer (score 2):

For such a trivial reducer, it may not be technically needed - but it's still good practice.

Spreading the existing state into the new state is useful when there are any properties in the existing state that you want to retain in the new state, without listing out each one individually, or without knowing what all they are. If you were to modify this reducer later to do something more complicated, in some sort of separate flow, the fact that you're spreading the existing state will mean that no additional modification to your existing code is needed; you just need to add the new actions, and things will work.

That said, in the case of `AUTH_FAIL`, you might consider setting `authData` to null, instead of possibly retaining old outdated `authData`.

```
case "AUTH_FAIL":
    return { ...state, loading: true, error: true, authData: null };
```

Comment: State should also be treated immutable, which works by default when state is a number, string, or Boolean. But for objects and arrays directly changing it value may cause unexpected results. [More info](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state)